# How to display jquery ui accordion and drupal 7

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, drupal-7

I am working with jQuery UI Accordion and Views in drupal7. My view various articles list, then in my view theme information take a name for my vista.tpl.php and copy the file in my theme. In that file add this:

```
      <meta charset="utf-8" />
  <!--<title>jQuery UI Accordion - Collapse content</title>-->
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.3/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css" />
  <?php print '<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.js"></script>';?>
  <?php print '<script src="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.3/jquery-ui.js"></script>';?>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="/resources/demos/style.css" />
  <?php print '<div id="accordion">';?>
     <?php print '<h3>Mostrar Resumen</h3>'; ?>
         <?php print '<div>'; ?>
           <?php print '<p>'; ?>
             <?php print $output; ?>
           <?php print '</p>'; ?> 
        <?php print '</div>'; ?>
   <?php print '</div>'; ?>
<?php print '<script>
  $(function() {
      $( "#accordion" ).accordion({ header: "h3", collapsible: true, active: false });
  });
  </script>';?>
```

the accordion only does the first item in the list, the rest does nothing. Any idea?

Comment: Any JS errors? Ctrl+Shift+J will give you the console in FF

Comment: Do you have JS errors?